# Azure Cordova Plugin with Azure AD B2C

Tags: cordova, azure, adal, azure-ad-b2c

I'm developing a Cordova app and I am looking for a solution to log in my users with the Azure AD B2C. The Azure Cordova plugin does not show the option to connect with Azure AD B2C.

I also tested the ADAL plugin but it doesn't work.

```
context.tokenCache.readItems().then(function (items) {
        if (items.length > 0) {
            authority = items[0].authority;
            context = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
        }
        // Attempt to authorize the user silently
        context.acquireTokenSilentAsync(resourceUri, clientId)
            .then(authCompletedCallback, function () {
                // We require user credentials, so this triggers the authentication dialog box
                context.acquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, clientId, redirectUri)
                    .then(authCompletedCallback, function (err) {
                        alert("Failed to authenticate: " + err);
                    });
            });
    });
```

My authority is : https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/[myTenant].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpOrSignIn

The login page is not show but i have à Server Error, 404 Not Found.
(I have the same if i click on the url).

**EDIT : 20170912**

Before I was using the authority : 'login.microsoftonline.com/[mytenant].onmicrosoft.com' 
as indicated in the doc

And my login page was the login page of Azure AD and not Azure AdB2C.

Now I have Changed the autority to 'login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/[mytenant].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpOrSignIn'

And my login page was a 404.
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fJdlj.png)

Comment: Can you include the error that you are getting in the question as well? Also, what authority are you using? You should use `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/yourtenant.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_yourpolicy`

Comment: Thanks for four answer , I have change the autoryty to : https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/[mytenant].onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1_SignUpOrSignIn. But I have a 404 page instead of the login page for my Azure AD B2C

Comment: So you were getting the login page for B2C before, can you please add screenshots and error messages to better explain what you mean by "it doesn't work"

Comment: I have edit my question with the screen picture off the login page with the  authority 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/tfp/yourtenant.onmicrosoft‌​.com/b2c_1_yourpolic‌​y

Comment: Sorry, I meant a screenshot with the other error, with your original authority